How to prevent preg_replace() ALTERING specific part of a string?
How do i prevent preg_replace() altering the content of () in following php-Snippet:
myVar.replace(/\u00AD/g, '');

This is my PHP function (I am not sure, which part is responsible):
$output = preg_replace('/true/', '!0', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:(?<!\:|\\\)\/\/[^"\'].*))/', '', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/ = /', '= ', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/\s*\n\s*/', '', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/([^A-Za-z0-9\_\$])\h/', '$1', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/\s?([\(\[{])\s?/', '$1', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/\s([\)\]}])/', '$1', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/;\n/', ';', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/;}/', '}', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/}\n/', '}', $output);

Thanks in advance ...

It's not clear what you're asking. What is the desired output? What is the actual output?

Regular expressions are not good at distinguishing "inside" and "outside" brackets, so it's really hard for preg_replace() to only do the replacements outside the parentheses.

The problem is matching arbitrary regex. If you know it is always that simple /\u00AD/g and will never contain parentheses, you may try adding myVar\.replace\(\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)| at the start of the patterns that can match something in that string. Otherwise, it is going to be harder.

How to let regex ignore everything between brackets? and relevant questions: PHP preg_replace all commas except those inside parentheses and PHP Regex ignore string between specific characters

@mickmackusa IIUC, they're using PHP preg_replace() to make changes to JavaScript source code. So "myVar.replace(/\u00AD/g, '');" is the value of $output

It looks like this is some kind of JS minifier (e.g. replacing true with !0).

Also topically relevant: Do not replace in between brackets in preg_replace? and Replace words - Ignore words between brackets and Remove text outside of {} () bracket and here's one with a Wiktor answer Regex replace word when not enclosed in brackets

You can also do preg_replace($pattern_array, $replacements_array, $the_string); and cut down on the boilerplate.
